# Debugger visualizer of GDI objects for unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gdi, visual-studio-debugging, debuggervisualizer

1. Technically, is there a way to show images (bitmaps, icons, cursors) directly inside the watch window? As far as I know there is no way to do that via `autoexp.dat`. (If not, a tool window will also do.)
2. How can I transfer the image data from the debuggee to the debugger visualizer?
3. What other (see below) resources or sample code exists for the problem at hand?

Aside from the MSDN documentation and examples, I found this: http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83 ... however, it "only" covers textual data. Virtually all other information was superficial (only covering "default" features of `autoexp.dat`) or for managed code.

Basically I am looking for [this](http://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/), but for unmanaged debuggees. The linked visualizer does not appear to work with unmanaged (C++) code, I tried that.

**Is there any solution for native code at all?**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188782.aspx#S9

Comment: @Hans: thank you. I will look into the code. Perhaps it would make sense to post the link as an answer? It is certainly helpful and at least partially (still reading) relevant to my problem :) ... thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've eventually stumbled upon your question while googling. I had exactly the same question, only for OpenCV, not GDI images. I found there is no simple solution for this task. However, I've implemented one based on Visual Studio [Debugging Expression Evaluator Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwk67y3%28VS.80%29.aspx).

My implementation is available as a VSIX package named [NativeViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nativeviewer/) at SourceForge. If you need, you can adapt it to work with GDI images instead of OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen my FeinViewer? I stopped supporting it for the lack of interest...

http://feinsoftware.com/FeinViewer.php

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't support the versions of Visual Studio I was interested in. In fact I had at some point in the past purchased your CommentMakerPro.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the visualizer by Mikhail, there is this one:

- http://victorhurdugaci.com/projects/vsimagevisualizer/